# How do i can check if my post string contains a symbol and prevent from proceeding

Tags: php, forms, input

Im making a simple search on my website for files in directory.
All files in it looks like `example.html`.

I already made that user can't search empty input and i wan't to prevent user from searching all that is in `$exclude` string. Otherwise if user will type in example dots, it will show every file  that is in directory.

---

Here is my php code:

```
$dir = "data/pages/";
$exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess','index'); 
if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
if (empty($_POST['field1'])) { 
    echo("<p><h3>Please fill all the fields</h3>");
}
else {
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            echo("<p><h3>&darr;Search Results&darr;</h3>");
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            if(preg_match("/{$_POST['field1']}/i", $filename) &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) {
                echo("<p>Found: <b><a href=\"https://mywebsite.wtf/data/pages/" . $file . "\">$filename</a>"); 
            }


            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: glob() finds pathnames, matching a pattern, maybe better to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending of the match (exact match or contain), you can do that:

if input contain some exclude:

```
        $isOk = true;
        $exclude = ['.','..','.htaccess','index'];
        foreach ($exclude as $exclude){
            if(str_contains($_POST['field1'], $exclude)){
                $isOk = false;
            }
        }
```

if input contain some exact input

```
        $isOk = true;
        $exclude = ['.','..','.htaccess','index'];
        if(in_array($_POST['field1'], $exclude, true)){
            $isOk = false;
        }
```

In your code, with exact check:

```
$dir = "data/pages/";
        $excludes = array('.','..','.htaccess','index');
        $isOk = true;
        if(in_array($_POST['field1'], $excludes, true)){
            $isOk = false;
        }
        if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
            if (empty($_POST['field1'])) {
                echo("<p><h3>Please fill all the fields</h3>");
            }
            if (!$isOk) {
                echo("<p><h3>You cannot search that!</h3>");
            }
            else {
                if (is_dir($dir)) {
                    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                        echo("<p><h3>&darr;Search Results&darr;</h3>");
                        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                            $filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                            if(preg_match("/{$_POST['field1']}/i", $filename) &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) {
                                echo("<p>Found: <b><a href=\"https://mywebsite.wtf/data/pages/" . $file . "\">$filename</a>");
                            }


                        }
                        closedir($dh);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you somehow adapt it in my code. Cause it's still not working correctly for me :)

Comment: i've edited my answer to match your request